# Kiel roboto ofendu biologiajn estaĵojn? (angla: "meatbag")

Tags: single-word-requests

Roboto ofendas homon, ĉar ĝi malestimas biologiajn estaĵojn.
Kiun vorton ĝi uzu?

Mi serĉas ekvivalenton de angla vorto "meatbag".

Comment: Kaj "ofendi" kaj "(mal)estimi" estas transitivaj verboj, do "ofendas la homo**n**" kaj "malestimas biologia**jn** estaĵo**jn**".

Comment: Dankon!
Kial "Kiel roboto ofendu" kaj ne "Kiel roboto ofendas" en la titolo?

Comment: La u-modo de verbo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato ne estas reala, sed dezirata, volata, ordonata aŭ celata. Do "Kiel roboto ofendu…" signifas, kion la roboto devas fari por ofendi (dezirata ago). Komparu kun "Kiel roboto ofendas…", kio priskribas, kion la roboto jam faras (reala ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tiu kunteksto vi povus uzi *organikulo*, *vivulo*, eble aldoni *aĉ* por substreki la malestimon: *vivulaĉo*.

Comment: Ambaŭ estas bonaj proponoj! Mi elektas _organikulon_, ĉar certe la roboto konsideras, ke ĝi mem estas vivanta. "Organikulo" estas pli trafa malo al la roboto, kaj oni povas uzi "aĉ" kiel atributo al ĝi: tiu aĉa organikulo!

Answer (score 2):

*Organikulaĉo* estas bona alternativo, eble iom serioza aŭ bombasta depende de la kunteksto. Por iom pli laŭvorta kaj pli "ofenda" traduko, mi dirus *aro da karno*, *marŝanta karno* aŭ *karnul(aĉ)o* (el PIV *karnulo; Mortideva homo*)